# Problema al recibir un array en json con android

Tags: java, android, json

Hola tengo un problema al recibir un array en json me da el siguiente error cuando hago debug en la app

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for codigo
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
        at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
        at com.primer.mimercado.ui.basededatos.BasededatosFragment$4.onResponse(BasededatosFragment.java:179)
        at com.primer.mimercado.ui.basededatos.BasededatosFragment$4.onResponse(BasededatosFragment.java:169)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae005240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xae0037c0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae005240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xae0037c0)
```

la respuesta de la web donde hago la consulta me responde lo siguiente

{"Ventas1":[{"codigo":"020800722452","descripcion":"OLD SPICE BARRA AFTER PARTY X50G"},{"codigo":"021200510052","descripcion":"GUANTES SCOTCH BRITE MULTIUSO 7-71.2"},{"codigo":"021200510069","descripcion":"GUANTES SCOTCH BRITE MULTIUSO"},{"codigo":"028400055093","descripcion":"PAPAS LAY S STAX ORIGINAL EST. X 155GRS."},{"codigo":"028400055116","descripcion":"PAPAS LAY S STAX (ACA SIGUE LA LISTA DE PRODUCTOS)

mi codigo en la app que recibe el json es el siguiente

```
  String url = "https://www.pediencasa.com/prueba1.php";
        url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Ventas1");
                    arraycodigos = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        arraycodigos.add(
                                new ProductosCodigos(
                                        jsonObject.getString("codigo"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("descripcion"),
                                        "8"
                                )
                        );

                    }
                    Context contexto = getContext();
                    recyclermanager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
                    adapterCodigos = new AdapterCodigos(arraycodigos, contexto);

                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterCodigos);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclermanager);

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "En este momento no podemos acceder a descargar, consulte mas tarde", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                error.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Al parecer hay un error, vuelve a intentar mas tarde", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);**
```

Answer (score 0):

tu problema es que no estas consultando los elementos del array, sino el objeto con el response

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject producto=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);//
    arraycodigos.add(
        new ProductosCodigos(
        producto.getString("codigo"),
        producto.getString("descripcion"),
        "8"
    );

}
```